# Gradle how to generate external library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In gradle (in Android Studio) you can import external libraries simply by defining an url, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.10'
}
```

I know that you can link local libraries. But that's not wanted, since we want to share a common library in a team. I wonder how to setup such a URL for an own library? Is it also possible to make it not public accessible?

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. We are using Gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a **Private** Git SCM like [Github](https://github.com/) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), you can easily turn it as a Maven repository and host your private library there. This can be used to refer libraries as dependencies in your projects just like you do with public libraries hosted on MavenCentral, JCenter or others.

You can get the detailed description for the same here: [Publish with Gradle on Bitbucket](https://medium.com/@Mul0w/publish-with-gradle-on-bitbucket-1463236dc460#.vjj4a4q8g)

Also you can refer this [link](https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/) to publish your library privately using JitPack. JitPack supports building and installing from private Git repositories. Build artifacts are also kept private and you can only download them if you have access to the Git repository itself.

You can also share your build artifacts (jar, aar) publicly while keeping the source code private. For example, you can easily distribute your library to your users without giving them access to code.